# Access sharepoint list from windows application

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone tell me if I have some ways to access to sharepoint list from windows app?

I've tryed following way (i'm under user that is sharepoint member):

```
SPUserToken token = new SPUserToken(
            BitConverter.GetBytes(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token.ToInt32()));
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteName, token);
```

but no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a web reference to query the SharePoint WebService's GetListItems web method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Like Jason said, to be able to use the SharePoint Object model (i.e. the sharepoint dll's) the app needs to be running on the same machine as SharePoint. If it is anywhere else you can only use the Web Services provided by SharePoint (or create your own and deploy that to your sharepoint server).

P.S. In SharePoint 2010 you have the client object model at your disposal, basically a subset of the full sharepoint object model (Kinda like Silverlight). Of course sp2010 is still in beta....

Answer (score 0):

Is `siteName` on the same computer that you are running the windows application from? If not, then you won't be able to access that site if you're using SharePoint 2007.

If the above isn't the problem, then check that the user account `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` is at least a site owner on `siteName`.